# Increment a variable in nasm assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am making a OS in 32-bit protected mode assembly and need to increment (or decrement) a variable. My variable is defined like this:

```
Var: db 1
```

and I am trying to increment it like this:

```
mov ebx, [Var]
inc ebx
mov [Var], ebx
```

However, the variable is increased by a value **WAY** bigger then 1. Why is this happening and how do I fix it.

Comment: `inc byte [Var]` should do it.  Or load with `movzx ebx, byte [Var]`, and store `bl`.  Even what you're doing, a wider load, will still properly increment the low byte, just disturb higher bytes with carry-out.  Possibly you have some other storage before `Var`, and are also using instructions wider than the space for them and are messing up Var that way.  Use a watchpoint in GDB or Bochs' built-in debugger to check when Var is getting modified.

Comment: Hello @PeterCordes, This did not work, I got the same resualt and the value was set to god knows what.

Comment: Like I said, your current buggy code will correctly increment the 1-byte `db 1` at that address, it's just a matter of not propagating carry into later bytes.  So if you're seeing nonsense, some other code is messing up the value, so this isn't a [mcve] of whatever problem you're having.  Use a debugger to check.  And if you haven't set DS properly, make sure segments are set properly so absolute addresses work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you defined `Var` to be a byte-sized variable, but you operate on it as if it was a dword-sized variable.  This causes you to read/write unrelated bytes around the variable, causing the strange numbers you observe.

To fix this, always operate on data with the correct data size.  For example, do

```
movzx ebx, byte [Var]
inc ebx
mov [Var], bl
```

Note the asymmetry: we could have used `mov bl, byte ptr [Var]`, but it's slow to write to partial registers (i.e. `bl` being a part of `ebx`).  The instruction `movzx` makes sure to write the full register while only fetching a single byte from memory.

Or even simpler

```
inc byte [Var]
```

Comment: Another solution would be to fix `Var` and make it a double word.